# Android SDK is not detecting my Android 2.3 phone, but still my system recognizes my device

Tags: android, sdk

i installed Android SDK and connected my Android 2.3 device (Debug-able) but for some reason, SDK manager is not recognizing my device. Is there anything that i'm doing wrong.

Comment: For what purpose does the SDK manager need to see your phone?

Comment: Actually I'm running out of internal memory on my device. Forum says that using sdk manager i can change the preferred storage location. There i started to explore on the websites to change the preferred location. All I wanted is to move my existing applications which are occupying my device's internal memory to SD card and any further applications to be installed must occupy my SD card space but not phone memory. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Which OS are using in host machine? Have you installed `Google USB Driver`?

Comment: i'm doing it.... My system works on XP........

Comment: I installed Google USB Driver but still no use... Also my device runs on 2.3.6 OS but the module downloaded by SDK manager is Android 2.3.3, does it have anything to do with my issue....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting adb server ?

If not try this:

- Create a batch file named `restart-adb-server.bat`
- Copy this batch file to the `platform-tools` directory of your Android SDK installation directory.
- then double click the batch file to restart the abd server and list the connected devices

The batch file content

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
cls
adb devices

pause
```

This may help you.